Does the proposed UK law on the ban of extreme protests groups include measures to prevent discredit?
There is an article reporting a new proposal to ban extreme protest groups. I don't know further details, would it include any measure to prevent discredit actions?
I mean preventing that any group of hired thugs carries out extreme protests in the name of this or that group in order to have it banned.
Related question.

Lord Walney's report is yet to be published, so we can't answer this question at the moment. Any recommendations in the report which are accepted by the government would then have to make their way into legislation. At the moment there is no proposed law. I'm going to close this question as right now it's asking for a prediction of future events.

It would be interesting to see if anybody from the opposition points it out.
